# Is it possible await a state value based condition in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I want to await the state value "loaded" to be true, how would I accomplish this with javascript promises?

My first instinct was to create an interval function which repeatedly checks if the value meets the condition and then resolves the promise. However, that doesn't seem to be an efficient solution.

Also, this may be important: I do not have access to any external fetching promises or anything like that. This questioned is directed towards purely the react state.

Comment: What do you want to do when it's true? The most common cases i can think of i'd probably solve with a useEffect, not a promise.

Comment: @NicholasTower I'm returning a promise so my suspense wrapper can render a fallback component in the meantime. Suspense fallback only works with promises, right?

Comment: Yes, suspense only works if you throw a promise. But suspense is also going to unmount your component and render the placeholder instead. Since your component isn't mounted, then its state doesn't exist. What does your loading code look like? If you want to use suspense you may need to extract that loading code outside of the component.

Answer (score 1):

From our discussion in the comments, i see you're trying to create a promise so it can be detected by a `<Suspense>` component farther up the tree. However, when suspense gets that promise, it's going to unmount your component, which means there's no longer any state that we could pay attention to it changing. So the resolution of your promise will need to be based on something other than state.

Here's an example of how you might throw a promise while loading:

```
let data = null;

let Example = () => {
  if (!data) {
    throw fetch('someUrl')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) throw result;
        return response.json();
      }).then(json => {
        data = json; // Saving the data to the global variable, so when the component rerenders it won't throw again
        return json;
      });
  }

  // render something with the data
}
```

Note however that this data will effectively be global. Every `Example` component will be interacting with the same `data` object. Maybe that's what you want, maybe not.

I'd also like to point out that using suspense for data loading isn't that common. There's some cool [future stuff](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) on the horizon once Concurrent Mode is finished, but until then, i generally recommend just handling it in your component with state and effects:

```
let Example = () => {
  const [data, setData] = null;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('someUrl')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) throw result;
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(setData);
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    // render the placeholder. There will be no suspense component surrounding this one needed
  } else {
    // render something with the data
  }
}
```